# Can this Noise Suppression Filter/ RF Inductor be used in buck/boost converter instead?

Tags: inductor, buck-boost

Say I have a buck/boost converter operating at 100Mhz. Would [this inductor](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/emc/emc/suppression-filter/catalog/suppression-filter_commercial_vaf201610fa-1_en.pdf) (VAF201610FA-841-1) be a good choice if I needed larger inductance, over other fixed inductors? (considering I do not surpass its current limit)

I am asking this, because I see the label "Noise Suppression Filter/ RF Inductor" in the datasheet and in the [mouser buying page](https://gr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TDK/VAF201610FA-841-1?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduikmMmlAkws4GRoXKSd82%252BUDxblTDLcDed3zYM75bTxIU5l%2FgGxz000)

So I do not know if there is any disadvantage using this inductor on buck/boost, over others that are just 'fixed inductors'. I also see that it has greater current capability compared to the simpler 'fixed inductors' I see in mouser.

Comment: I would not choose that inductor as it doesn't show at which current it saturates (magnetically). For a DCDC converter the energy that is converterted is stored in the inductor as magnetic flux. It is unclear how much energy this inductor can store. It is also not designed for that. It is actually designed to "get rid of the energy" as it is designed to filter. And as Marcus already answered, it is unlikely that you have a 100 MHz DCDC converter. I have designed DCDC converters and 10 MHz was a huge challenge already (if you want decent efficiency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I have a buck/boost converter operating at 100Mhz.

It's very unlikely you've got a buck/boost operating at 100 MHz, for physical reasons of switching losses and core losses.

As you've noticed, core materials don't work like perfect inductors once frequencies rise.

So, if your inductor has any core material that is frequency-dependent (mostly: anything but air-core) you'll have to make sure it's *not* lossy at high frequencies. The opposite of what you're looking at.